# Generate excel from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, excel

I have written all the code to generate excel in an ASPX page named `GenerateXLS.aspx` and I am calling the export to excel from javascript as

```
var BudgetID = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CmbBudget").value;
var BudgetType = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CmbBudgetType").value;
var CompanyID = document.getElementById('<% =HidCompanyID.ClientID %>').value;
var UserID = document.getElementById('<% =HidUserID.ClientID %>').value;
var BudgetName = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CmbBudget").options[document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CmbBudget").selectedIndex].text;
var BudgetTypeName = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CmbBudgetType").options[document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CmbBudgetType").selectedIndex].text;

document.getElementById("iFrame_Excel").src = "../Reports/GenerateXLS.aspx?Source=BudgetReport&BudgetID=" + BudgetID + "&BudgetType=" + BudgetType + "&CompanyID=" + CompanyID + "&UserID=" + UserID + "&BudgetName=" + BudgetName + "&BudgetTypeName=" + BudgetTypeName;   alert("works now");
```

**The problem is it is generating the excel, but only if I keep the alert at the end of the javascript function.**  If I remove the alert from my function, the page is getting posted back but not generating the excel file. What might be the problem? Why is it generating the excel file only if I keep the alert?

Comment: this piece of code is inside a callback? i.e. behaviour of <A> click event?

Comment: try putting this in an ajax request instead of a `<a>`. That way the response will get captured and your page will generate the Excel too

Comment: @Alberto No. The entire coe I have provided is in a javascript function. And I am calling onclientclick of button

Comment: do you invoke a preventDefault() on event? e.preventDefault()

Comment: @Alberto :  Super. It is working with e.preventDefault(). Thank Youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Comment: mind if I add it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `e.preventDefault();` to avoid reload and, if you have to go to a specific URL after function execution, `window.location.href = your_url;`